# Download list of the name of every airport in Western languages

Tags: data-request, geospatial, travel

I am looking for a list of all airports in all countries in all Western languages. At least, in all EU languages in a CSV or tab-separated download.

Would appreciate any pointers

Comment: Try [this Wikidata query](http://tinyurl.com/ycp39lwp).

Answer (score 2):

For a start try the [OpenFlights Airports Database](http://openflights.org/data.html#airport). It gives you a list of all airports in English. I don't know if you have any programming skills but from there you could try to use the [translate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-translate) module in python.

- Create a file with only the names
- Use the module for looping through the file and trough your desiered languages
- Write the results in a list/directory and rewrite them into a file

Answer (score 0):

You can use Overpass API to query Openstreetmap for airports:

```
/* select all airports, regardless of node, way or relation */
(node[aeroway=aerodrome]({{bbox}});
 way[aeroway=aerodrome]({{bbox}});
 rel[aeroway=aerodrome]({{bbox}});
 ); 
/* recurse down, so map displays something. */
 (._;(>););
out;
```

[Execute the query.](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/nCY)

At least on international Airports, you can expect `name:xx` tags, where xx is a iso2 language code. Note that the language of `name` is in default langauge, spoken in the respective country.

Data Quality is as always, well, OSM-like.